# Finding average of previous value in array using a smooth constant

Tags: javascript

I have an array of values like this `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

I have a smoothing constant which takes `1`,`2`,`3`,...`30`

if `smoothConstant = 1;`

I should find average of the previous 1 value for each element, since first value can't be smoothed with previous value it goes as such and my array should look like

`[1, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5]`

if `smoothConstant = 2;`

My array should be smoothed with previous two values, as below result

`[1, 1.5, 2((3+2+1)/3), 3((4+3+2)/3), 4((5+4+3)/3).... ]`

I'm little confused on how to proceed with this logic

Comment: Can you please provide some sample inputs and outputs? I'm personally quite confused.

Comment: @briosheje it is there in the question

Comment: it's unclear, to me, what's the input (other than the array) and how the output is actually transformed. I will try to read the question again.

Comment: @briosheje if you have questions please let me know I can clarify it better

Comment: Smooth from the etymology means kinda of with respect to or at least in my vernacular  / slang lookup, hence... modulo congruence

Comment: @Aravind given input `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];` and smoothConstant `2`, why is the output for the first two elements `[1,1.5]`? Shouldn't that be `[1,2]`? I had a "working" solution, but that gave me `[1,2]` instead of `[1,1,5]`, since the element at index `1` doesn't have two previous values, am I wrong?

Comment: @briosheje that is the trick here it has to be smoothed with the previous values until it reaches the smoothing constant

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12026/what-does-smooth-curve-mean

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem

The first example shows that it's possible for negative numbers....

Comment: `given {\displaystyle \varepsilon >0} \varepsilon >0, there exists {\displaystyle 0<\delta <1} 0<\delta<1 `

Answer (score 2):

Building upon the [answer of junvar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57497459/3982562).

I added the option to provide negative values, which does what you would expect. Providing -1 takes the next 1 element end averages it with the current.

Furthermore I also added a third argument, through wich you can provide a callback to access a certain attribute if needed. This defaults to `obj => obj` which translates to the element itself.

```js
function smooth(constant, array, callback = obj => obj) {
  return array.map((_element, index) => {
    var [start, end] = [Math.max(index - constant, 0), index].sort((a, b) => a - b),
        subArray = array.slice(start, end + 1);
    return subArray.reduce((acc, nr) => acc + callback(nr), 0) / subArray.length;
  });
}

console.log(smooth(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
console.log(smooth(1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
console.log(smooth(0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
console.log(smooth(-1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
console.log(smooth(-2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
console.log(smooth(1, [{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}], obj => obj.value));
```

Comment: I think we should for `Math.max(_element,...`

Answer (score 1):

```js
smooth = (array, smoothConstant) =>
 array.map((_, i) => {
  let slice = array.slice(Math.max(i - smoothConstant, 0), i + 1);
  return slice.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / slice.length;
 });

let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
console.log(smooth(a, 1));
console.log(smooth(a, 2));
```

For objects such as `[{ id:1, value:1},{ id:2, value:2},...]`, as requested in comments, simply map your array `a.map(({value} => value)` before calling `smooth`.

Comment: This looks like great one, can I use this for a json object which has the value in a property each object will look like this `[{ id:1, value:1},{ id:2, value:2},...]`

Comment: smooth([1, 0, -1], 0.5) == smooth([1, 0, -1], 1), but smooth([1, 0, -1], -1) is `Reduce of empty array with no initial value` ... What type of smooth curve this is exactly I am not sure... hence my down vote.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. However you start at the wrong index. When an `smoothConstant` of `1` is given you don't average it with any previous elements and it will just return itself. Remove the `+ 1` in `i - smoothConstant + 1` and your answer matches the question.

Comment: @Jay The question asks about previous values, not further values. If OP wants this functionality he can extend the answer with it.

Comment: @Jay, read the OP's question and it should be obvious smoothConstant can only be positive integers.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, I think you're mistaken. The +1 is necessary otherwise, it will skip the first element. E.g. `smooth([1, 2], 1)` correctly returns `[1, 2]`.

Comment: But he said previous and you used the inverse... I still don't agree but whatever it's my rep point. Good job... I guess. Regards...

Comment: @Jay, Agreed, he said "previous", but his example demonstrates he meant "previous including current". I guess it's not as obvious, but still I assumed "previous including current" would be more desirable.

Comment: @junvar your assumption was absolutely right! I want it to be previous + current, can I use this logic for json objects as I mentioned in the first comment?

Comment: Then this is not necessarily smooth.... given arbitrary values right? I can pick this apart if I needed to....Hence my down-vote to the question now.

Comment: I.e. Half of your answer is likely smoother than the previous lol... (or other half) haha

Comment: @Jay why do you have to down vote, I felt the term smoothing is kind of correct, don't take exact meaning for the `smoothing`

Comment: @junvar - can we use this solution for the JSON objects?

Comment: @Aravind Yes, add an callback function as argument then call that to retrieve the value. The function definition is going to be `smooth = (array, smoothConstant, callback = obj => obj) => ...`, then change `slice.reduce((a, b) => a + b)` to `slice.reduce((a, b) => a + callback(b))`. Now you can do `smooth(array, 1, elem => elem.value)`

Comment: @Jay You should post that under the question, this answer is merely providing an answer to what is asked.

Comment: @Jay No where in the question I mentioned about smooth curve. I may have used the terms but I didn't mean it as smooth curve at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a sum variable and add the actual value and remove the value which is now outside. Then take the average.

```js
const
    smooth = (n, s = 0) => {
        n++;
        return (v, i, a) => (s += v - (a[i - n] || 0)) / Math.min(n, i + 1);
    }

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

console.log(...array.map(smooth(1)));
console.log(...array.map(smooth(2)));
```

Comment: For those who find the code a bit cryptic: `n = number`, `s = sum`, `v = value`, `i = index`, `a = array`

Answer (score 0):

It's mad early and I barely slept last night but this is eerily similar in some ways to something dumb I was working on.

As coincidence may have it I have it right in front of me...

Here you go, hope it helps...

```
//Extrapolation / Bilinear interpolation
const deduct = function deduct(start, end, progress) {
    return start + (end - start) / progress;
};

const congruence = function congruence(start, end) {
    return start + (end - (end % start))
};

 const ModularAdd = function ModularAdd(i, n){
    return (i % n + n) % n;
};
const ModularSubtract = function ModularSubtract(i, n){
    return (i % n - n) % n;
};
//Basically increment i and return the element in w which is modulo i and the length or in the step of i and s
const ModularStep = function ModularStep(w, i, s) {
    //reuturn Next(w, i) - Next(i);
    const n = Next(w, i);
    //< 0 indicates no items or value.
    if (n < Zero) return n; //Previous(n)?
    //If n === 0 i was the last greater
    const max = w.length - One;
    if (n === Zero) return i !== Zero ? max % i : max;
    s = s || One;
    //For 0 handle without i integrated otherwise integrate the step with addition
    //Todo there is another form where because this can be something other than add or subtract
    //Previous(i)?
    return i === Zero ? n * s : s * ModularAdd(n, i);
};
```

Regards

Comment: which function should I call?

Comment: Which parameter takes the array and which takes the constant?

Comment: const Next = function Next(w, i) { i = i || Zero; return isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(w) ? -One : i < w.length - One ? ++i : Zero; };    
    const Previous = function Previous(w, i) { i = i || Zero; return isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(w) ? -One : i > Zero ? --i : Zero; };